# Flatten semi-structured data without key : value pairs - Snowflake

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an array json data loaded into snowflake in the form of:

[[col1, col2, col3, col4], [a1, a2, a3, a4], [b1, b2, b3, b4], [c1, c2, c3, c4]... ect]

The array the array is currently read into snowflake as a table, data_table, with 1 row (the array above) and 1 column imaginatively named data_array

I need to flatten the array so that the first element is the column headings and the elements after column values.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |
| b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 |

The only flattening solutions I can find uses data in key value pairs eg {[col1:a1, col2:a2..], [col1:b1, col2:b2..].. ect}.

Is how do I go about flattening this data type in snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this isn't exactly what you are looking for, but hopefully it may be a starting point for you?

```sql
select
    GET(s.value::ARRAY, 0)::varchar as col1,
    GET(s.value::ARRAY, 1)::varchar as col2,
    GET(s.value::ARRAY, 2)::varchar as col3,
    GET(s.value::ARRAY, 3)::varchar as col4
from
    json_2 j,
    lateral flatten (input => j.src, mode => 'ARRAY') s
    -- lateral flatten (input => s.value, path => '', mode => 'ARRAY') s2
having
    col1 != 'col1'
;
```

This produces the output you are after. If you can provide more detail regarding further requirements I may be able to refine this further.

---

Code to generate test data set:

```sql
create or replace table play.ground.json_2 (src variant);

insert into play.ground.json_2(src) select parse_json($$
[["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"], ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"], ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"], ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]]
$$);

select * from json_2;
```